Problem with POST for vimeo thumbnail creation
Node JS. I constantly get a 503 error from the vimeo API with a POST request when trying to create a resource for the thumbnail I want to upload.
I wait until all transcoding is complete before making the request. The image path is valid.
Any ideas where I'm going wrong?
async function uploadThumbnail(token, videoId, imagePath) {
    console.log("uploadThumbnail: ", token, videoId, imagePath);
    
    // Define the metadata URI for the thumbnail
    const metadataUri = `https://api.vimeo.com/videos/${videoId}?fields=metadata.connections.pictures.uri`;

    try {
        // Step 1: Get the URI for the thumbnail
        const metaResponse = await axios.get(metadataUri, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
            }
        });
        const picturesUri = metaResponse.data.metadata.connections.pictures.uri;
        console.log("picturesUri", picturesUri); // returns e.g. "/videos/942054945/pictures"

        // Step 2: Create a resource for the thumbnail
        const createPicResponse = await axios.post(`https://api.vimeo.com${picturesUri}`, {}, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
            }
        });
        console.log("createPicResponse data:", createPicResponse.data); //fails

        const uploadLink = createPicResponse.data.link; //fails
        console.log("uploadLink", uploadLink);

        // Step 3: Upload the thumbnail file
        const imageData = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);
        const uploadResponse = await axios.put(uploadLink, imageData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', // Ensure the MIME type matches your image
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
            }
        });
        console.log('Upload successful', uploadResponse.data);

        // Step 4: Set the thumbnail as active
        const setThumbActiveUri = createPicResponse.data.uri;
        console.log("setThumbActiveUri", setThumbActiveUri);
        await axios.patch(`https://api.vimeo.com${setThumbActiveUri}`, { active: true }, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
            }
        });

        return "Thumbnail uploaded and set successfully";
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in thumbnail upload process:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        throw error; // Propagate the error up to handle it in the endpoint handler
    }
}

Edit:
When I apply the cURL command directly in NodeJS, it works fine.
// Step 2: Create a resource for the thumbnail
        const curlCommand = `curl -X POST "https://api.vimeo.com${picturesUri}" -H "Authorization: bearer ${token}" -H "Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4"`;
        const { stdout } = await execProm(curlCommand);
        const response = JSON.parse(stdout);
        console.log("createPicResponse data:", response);

        const uploadLink = response.link;
        console.log("Upload Link:", uploadLink);

I don't understand why. I've noticed this with FFMEG also - the cURL works but the (pure) javascript doesn't. Is it an async / await issue?
async function uploadThumbnail(token, videoId, imagePath) { //this works
    console.log("uploadThumbnail: ", token, videoId, imagePath);
    
    // Define the metadata URI for the thumbnail
    const metadataUri = `https://api.vimeo.com/videos/${videoId}?fields=metadata.connections.pictures.uri`;

    try {
        // Step 1: Get the URI for the thumbnail
        const metaResponse = await axios.get(metadataUri, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
            }
        });
        const picturesUri = metaResponse.data.metadata.connections.pictures.uri;
        console.log("picturesUri", picturesUri);

        // Step 2: Create a resource for the thumbnail
        const curlCommand = `curl -X POST "https://api.vimeo.com${picturesUri}" -H "Authorization: bearer ${token}" -H "Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4"`;
        const { stdout } = await execProm(curlCommand);
        const response = JSON.parse(stdout);
        console.log("createPicResponse data:", response);

        const uploadLink = response.link;
        console.log("Upload Link:", uploadLink);

        // Step 3: Upload the thumbnail file
        const imageData = await fs.readFile(imagePath);
        const uploadResponse = await axios.put(uploadLink, imageData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg', // Ensure the MIME type matches your image
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
            }
        });
        console.log('Upload successful', uploadResponse.data);

        // Step 4: Set the thumbnail as active
        const setThumbActiveUri = response.uri;
        console.log("setThumbActiveUri", setThumbActiveUri);
        const activeResponse = await axios.patch(`https://api.vimeo.com${setThumbActiveUri}`, { active: true }, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4'
            }
        });

        console.log("Thumbnail set as active", activeResponse.data);
        return "Thumbnail uploaded and set successfully";
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in thumbnail upload process:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        throw error; // Propagate the error up to handle it in the endpoint handler
    }
}

